# Camel XML config using header values in endpoint URI

Tags: xml, spring, apache-camel

I want to write the equivalent of this in Spring XML camel context notation.

```
                from("rabbitmq:resultQueue")
                    .filter(header("synchronousRequestId").isEqualTo(
                            synchronousRequestId))
                    .to("seda:" + synchronousRequestId).onCompletion()
                    .stop();
```

I don't know how to do this bit..

```
.to("seda:" + synchronousRequestId)
```

since synchronousRequestId is a header parameter and not a String constant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML version of it would be:

```
<recipientList>
     <simple>seda:${headers.synchronousRequestId}</simple>
</recipientList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer in [Apache Camel website's FAQ](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-dynamic-uri-in-to.html)

> Use the Recipient List EIP pattern, which allows you to compute the dynamic URI using an Expression.